# Change multi-cursor editing shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

Right now in order to perform a multi-cursor edit in SublimeText3 I press `Ctrl` and click the places I want to edit.

I want to change this so I press `Alt` (instead of 'Ctrl') and then click the places I want to edit.

I feeling like it should be somewhere in `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings`, but I was not able to find the option.

How can I change this key binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the bindings here are for mouse buttons and not for keyboard keys, the actual bindings are not stored in `sublime-keymap` files and are instead stored in `sublime-mousemap` files. This is a format similar to a `sublime-keymap` file, but it includes the ability to map a command to mouse buttons, click counts and modifier keys.

> **Note:** unlike a key binding, it's not possible to include a `context` key, so mouse bindings are an all-or-nothing affair; you can't set some to only apply in some circumstances and not others, for example.

In order to modify the mouse bindings you need to follow the same general procedure as you would for a key binding, which is to create a file with the appropriate name in your `User` package that includes your modified bindings. There aren't any default menu items or command palette entries that allow you to edit the mouse mappings, so you need to do this manually.

> **Note:** In the following file names, `$PLATFORM` is one of `Windows`, `OSX` or `Linux` depending on what platform you're on (case is important). Your question doesn't mention which platform you're on, so the instructions below assume `Windows`; change the platform as needed for your own uses. On OSX your bindings can include `super` to represent the `command` key, as they can in key bindings.

Where the name of a key binding file is `Default ($PLATFORM).sublime-keymap`,the appropriate file for mouse bindings is `Default ($PLATFORM).sublime-mousemap`. Additionally, like most resource files that set the default behaviour, the base files are stored in the `Default` package.

If you use the `View Package File` command palette entry to open `Default/Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`, you can see all of the default mouse bindings. There are two bindings in particular that you probably want to work with here, and they're near the top of the file in the "Basic drag select" section:

```json
{
    "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
    "press_command": "drag_select",
    "press_args": {"additive": true}
},
{
    "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["alt"],
    "press_command": "drag_select",
    "press_args": {"subtractive": true}
},
```

The first binding says that when the Left mouse button (`button1`) is clicked a single time while the `ctrl` key is pressed, the `drag_select` command should be executed with an argument that indicates the selection should be `added` to.

Similarly, the second binding uses `alt` instead of `ctrl` and executes the same command, telling it to `subtract` from the selection instead of adding to it.

Thus, <kbd>Ctrl+Left Click</kbd> adds a caret (and any text you drag over) to the selection while <kbd>Alt+Left Click</kbd> does the reverse and removes carets and text you drag over.

To effect the change you want, create a file with the following contents and save  it as `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` in your `User` package (you can use `Preferences > Browse Packages` to find where that is).

> **Note:** If such a file already exists, add the two bindings here to the existing file instead of saving over it; in that case don't include the `[` and `]` characters, but make sure you paste the bindings in between the ones in the existing file along with the other bindings.

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"additive": true}
    },
    {
        "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"subtractive": true}
    },
]
```

This is the two bindings from above, but with the modifiers swapped. That makes the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key add selections and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> remove selection, effectively reversing their actions.

If you like you only need to add the binding for `alt`. However if you do that, the binding for `ctrl` will still exist, meaning you will have two bindings for adding a selection and no bindings for removing a selection. That may or may not be of concern depending on how much you rely on that particular binding.